# Can the browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) authenticate to a SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: browser, authentication, socks-proxy

If so, what authentication method is possible?

Comment: Pretty sure all the browsers can do the auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browsers don't do the authentication very well.  I use tsocks or proxychains to do the proxy functions and authentication.  Anything supported by the server is probably supported by proxychains - username/password certificates symmetric encryption...there are ways to do it all.  I like to abstract it so the browser doesn't even know it's being proxied though.

Comment: Could you clarify "very well", is there *any* support for authentication in the common browsers? I didn't see any.

Comment: I haven't played with it in a while...it seems like IE used to support some form of auth in proxy settings.  it might have only been username password though.  check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169/how-do-i-write-firefox-add-on-that-automatically-enters-proxy-passwords  they note where to find ntlm auth configurations.  IE does ntlm auth by default now.  all in all the builtin auth is pretty automatic and pretty weak